# libxml reader: How do I read attribute value such that the entity reference are preserved?

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I'm using the libxml2 streaming reader and I am having trouble reading entity references. When an entity reference is within an elements contents it is treated as a node of type `XML_READER_TYPE_ENTITY_REFERENCE` which can be read like so:

Sample XML:

```
<p>Wikipedia&reg; is a registered trademark</p>
```

Sample C code:

```
xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
if (xmlTextReaderNodeType(reader) == XML_READER_TYPE_ENTITY_REFERENCE)
{
     const xmlChar *entityRef = xmlTextReaderConstName(reader);
     ///entityRef will be "reg"
}
```

The reader does issues the following warning, but it's it has no consequence on the parsing:

```
file://localhost/Volumes/Users/ben/testdata.html:1001: parser error : Entity 'reg' not defined
Wikipedia&reg; is a registered trademark of the <a href="http://www.wikimediafou
              ^
```

Things are not as simple when the entity reference is within an attribute:

Sample XML:

```
<img alt="random text containing &reg; entity reference" src="notImportant" />
```

I am reading the attributes like so:

```
while (xmlTextReaderMoveToNextAttribute(self.reader) == 1)
{
    const xmlChar *attribName  = xmlTextReaderConstName(self.reader);
    const xmlChar *attribValue = xmlTextReaderConstValue(self.reader);

    //process the attribute
}
```

If the attribute value contains an entity reference `attribValue` omits it, eg:

```
//attribValue = "random text containing  entity reference"
```

How do I retrieve the attribute value such that the entity reference is not lost?

(I think the way to do this is to read the attribute value use `xmlReaderRead` so that the value is treated as `XML_READER_TYPE_ENTITY_REFERENCE` and `XML_READER_TYPE_TEXT` nodes, but I can't figure out how to do that.)